# High-Resolution Processing Output

Tags: java

I'm looking for help with the programming language/environment Processing.

I'm fairly new to Processing and I am experimenting with a piece of code from someone over at openprocessing.org. I really like the visual results this code delivers and I would like to further work with it. Unfortunately, the output is very low resolution. Hence I'm looking for someone who might be able to help me figure out how to a) Increase the size or resolution of the shapes generated and b) save everything as a pdf file.

You can find the original code in action here: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/377730

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
float[][] z, v, a;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  size(512, 512);
  colorMode(RGB, 2);
  z = new float[width][height];
  v = new float[width][height];
  a = new float[width][height];
  loadPixels();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void draw() {
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      a[x][y] = (v[x-1][y] + v[x+1][y] + v[x][y-1] + v[x][y+1])/4 - v[x][y];
    }
  }
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      v[x][y] += a[x][y];
      z[x][y] += v[x][y];
      pixels[width*y+x] = color(sin(z[x][y]) + 1, cos(z[x][y]), 1);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void move() {
  if (mouseX > -1    &&    mouseX < width    &&    mouseY > -1    &&    mouseY < height) {
    v[mouseX][mouseY] = randomGaussian() * TAU;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseClicked() { move(); }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseDragged() { move(); }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void keyPressed() {
  noLoop();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)    Arrays.fill(z[x], 0);
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)    Arrays.fill(v[x], 0);
  loop();
}
```

So far I have experimented with a supposed high-resolution method posted to the Processing-Forum, which hasn't worked for me though, at least not in the context of the code above I'm working with. Here's the piece of code from the forum which demonstrates one user's way of saving the output of a Processing output in a high resolution:

```
int dim = 5000;
int dimScreen = dim/10;
color c1 = #AFA786;
color c2 = #000000;

void setup() { size(dimScreen,dimScreen); }
void draw()  { exampleSketch(); }

void exampleSketch() {
  for (int y=0; y<=height; y++) {
    stroke(lerpColor(c1,c2,float(y)/height));
    line(0,y,width,y);
  }
  stroke(#FFFFFF);
  fill(#BBBBBB);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
  line(0, 0, width, height);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key ==' ') {
    g = createGraphics(dim,dim,JAVA2D);
    this.height = dim;
    this.width = dim;
    g.beginDraw();
    exampleSketch();
    g.endDraw();
    save("result.png");
    println("screenshot saved");
    this.height = dimScreen;
    this.width = dimScreen;
  }
}
```

I'd be hugely grateful to anyone who's proficient enough with Processing and Java to help me out. Thanks so much and have a good night.

Here is my attempt of implementing the second code into the first one:

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
float[][] z, v, a;

int dim = 900;
int dimScreen = dim/10;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  smooth(8);
  colorMode(RGB, 2);
  z = new float[width][height];
  v = new float[width][height];
  a = new float[width][height];
  loadPixels();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void draw()  { exampleSketch(); }


void exampleSketch() {

  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      a[x][y] = (v[x-1][y] + v[x+1][y] + v[x][y-1] + v[x][y+1])/4 - v[x][y];
    }
  }
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      v[x][y] += a[x][y];
      z[x][y] += v[x][y];
      pixels[width*y+x] = color(sin(z[x][y]) + 1, cos(z[x][y]), 1);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void move() {
  if (mouseX > -1    &&    mouseX < width    &&    mouseY > -1    &&    mouseY < height) {
    v[mouseX][mouseY] = randomGaussian() * TAU;

  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseClicked() { move(); }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseDragged() { move(); }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void keyPressed() {
  if (key ==' ') {
    g = createGraphics(dim,dim,JAVA2D);
    this.height = dim;
    this.width = dim;
    g.beginDraw();
    exampleSketch();
    g.endDraw();
    save("result2.png");
    println("screenshot saved");
    this.height = 900;
    this.width = 900;
  }
}
```

*Edit:* Two screenshots comparing the different visual results before and after implementing George's solution for a white background:

[image: Before] [image: After]

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what doesn't work about the second piece of code? Also, what resolution are you targeting? How do you want the effect to scale?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

I tried implementing the saving method from the second code into the first one (with my limited knowledge of how Processing and Java works). I added the modified code to my original post above.

Unfortunately, the saved png contains nothing.

Comment: What resolution are you targeting? Do you want the output to be larger, or the sketch window to be larger, or do you want the sketch window to stay the same but just have larger blobs of color? Does it have to export as a `pdf`, or is it okay to export as an image file?

Comment: I'm looking to either make the output larger or the blobs of color to be larger. Basically, I am planning to later bring an image of the result into Photoshop and print it (ideally with a resolution of 300dpi, without the image being pixilated). Either an image file export (.tiff) or a pdf would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're really talking about two different things:

**Thing One:** Making the colored blobs bigger. This is a little annoying because the algorithm uses the pixels array, so it's not as simple as calling the `scale()` function.

In fact, because the algorithm works on pixels, any simple approach for changing the resolution is going to become pixelated.

[image: pixelated]

The solution you got on the forum is to draw to an off-screen buffer, which won't actually change the size of the blobs. **The only way to change the size of the blobs is to change your algorithm.**

You might be able to modify how you're manipulating the arrays so the blobs are larger, but honestly I don't totally understand exactly what the arrays are doing now, which makes it hard to help.

**Thing Two:** Exporting as an image.

The easiest way to do this is to simply call the `save("ImageNameHere.png")` function. That will create an image with the same size as your sketch that contains whatever was showing on the screen when the function was called.

The solution you found on the forum uses an off-screen buffer, but again: **that won't help with the size of the blobs.** You can indeed use an off-screen buffer to draw to an image that's larger than the sketch window, but that's only half of what you want. Saving this way is useless if your blobs are still small!

So, my advice for you is to fix **Thing One** first, and come up with an algorithm that generates larger blobs. Then we can talk about scaling and exporting as an image, which will be pretty easy once you have the algorithm working.

Comment: Alright. Thanks so much for your help up to this point. I will sit down and try to get a more full understanding of whats happening with the arrays here in order to manipulate the size of the blobs. If you can give me any further advice or have any idea of how I might go about doing that, that would be fantastic. Thanks again, have a good night.

Comment: Furthermore, do you think it would make sense to post this specific problem (of creating bigger blobs or even of creating the same sort of effect with another method, not pixel-based as in the version I'm using right now) as a new question here on StackOverflow?

Comment: @JohnGalt Honestly, that might be a little **too broad** for Stack Overflow.  There are a ton of different ways to approach the problem, and Stack Overflow isn't really built for general "how do I do this" type questions. Same with most places on the internet. It's much easier to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.

Comment: @JohnGalt I will say that my general answer to a "how do I do this" type of question is to **break your problem down into smaller steps.** Ask yourself how you would do this with a piece of paper and a pencil, and write down those instructions in English. When you have that written down, that's your algorithm that you can start implementing.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for your help. And in the long run I will get much more out of the whole thing when breaking it down and investigating the answers I need myself.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's answer, you can use [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to see where most of the CPU time is spent on. After sampling and profiling the CPU at different times surprisingly most of the time was computing the RGB values:

[image: jvisualvm screenshot1]

[image: jvisualvm screenshot2]

[image: jvisualvm screenshot3]

It's best to start with the functions taking most of the CPU when optimizing.

Here is a version of the sketch that uses the default 0-255 RGB range and computes the RGB value inlined (putting the A,R,G,B bytes together):

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
float[][] z, v, a;

int dim = 900;
int dimScreen = dim/10;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  smooth(8);
  //colorMode(RGB, 2);
  z = new float[width][height];
  v = new float[width][height];
  a = new float[width][height];
  loadPixels();

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void draw()  { exampleSketch(); }


void exampleSketch() {

  int r,g,b = 255;
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      a[x][y] = (v[x-1][y] + v[x+1][y] + v[x][y-1] + v[x][y+1]) * .25 - v[x][y];
    //}
  //}
//  //for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    //for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      v[x][y] += a[x][y];
      z[x][y] += v[x][y];
      r = ((int)((sin(z[x][y]) + 1) * 128) << 16);
      g = ((int)((cos(z[x][y]) * 128)) << 8);
      pixels[width*y+x] = 0xff000000 | r | g | b;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  fill(0);
  text((int)frameRate+"fps",15,15);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void move() {
  if (mouseX > -1    &&    mouseX < width    &&    mouseY > -1    &&    mouseY < height) {
    v[mouseX][mouseY] = randomGaussian() * TAU;

  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseClicked() { move(); }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseDragged() { move(); }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int screenshotCount=1;
void keyPressed() {
  if (key ==' ') {
    save("result"+nf(screenshotCount,4)+".png");
    println("screenshot saved");
  }
}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350644/high-resolution-processing-output
```

*Update*:
Here's an a modified function that maps the values so the background is white:

```
void exampleSketch() {
  float rv,gv;
  int r,g,b = 255;
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      //compute accumulated value of neighbour cells(left+right+top+bottom), average (/4 or * .25) then subtract the current cell from v
      a[x][y] = (v[x-1][y] + v[x+1][y] + v[x][y-1] + v[x][y+1]) * .25 - v[x][y];
      //increment current v cell by the current accumulated cell
      v[x][y] += a[x][y];
      //increment current z (final/result) cell by the updated v cell
      z[x][y] += v[x][y];
      //in short z[x][y] += v[x][y] + ((v[-1][0] + v[+1][0] + v[0][-1] + v[0][+1]) / 4 - v[x][y])
      //scale sin(z) and cos(z) results to 0-255: sin/cos returns -1.0 to 1.0 then 1.0 is added -> 0.0 to 2.0 , then 128 is multiplied = 0-255
      rv = (sin(z[x][y]) + 1.0) * 128;
      gv = (cos(z[x][y]) + 1.0) * 128;
      //contrain to 0-255
      if(rv < 0)   rv = 0;
      if(rv > 255) rv = 255;
      if(gv < 0)   gv = 0;
      if(gv > 255) gv = 255;
      //cast to int and shift
      r = ((int)(rv) << 16);
      g = ((int)(gv) << 8);
      //alpha (0xff000000) cobined with r , g, b 
      int argb = 0xff000000 | r | g | b;
      pixels[width*y+x] = argb;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  fill(0);
  text((int)frameRate+"fps",15,15);
}
```

Heres what I could save:

[image: result 1]

[image: result 2]

[image: result 3]

**Update 2**:
Here is a version that computes a transparency value instead of white:

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
float[][] z, v, a;

int dim = 900;
int dimScreen = dim/10;

PImage canvas;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  smooth(8);
  //colorMode(RGB, 2);
  z = new float[width][height];
  v = new float[width][height];
  a = new float[width][height];
  loadPixels();


  canvas = createImage(width,height,ARGB);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void draw()  { exampleSketch(); }


void exampleSketch() {
  float rs,gc,rv,gv;
  int r,g,b = 255;
  for (int x = 1; x < width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < height-1; y++) {
      //compute accumulated value of neighbour cells(left+right+top+bottom), average (/4 or * .25) then subtract the current cell from v
      a[x][y] = (v[x-1][y] + v[x+1][y] + v[x][y-1] + v[x][y+1]) * .25 - v[x][y];
      //increment current v cell by the current accumulated cell
      v[x][y] += a[x][y];
      //increment current z (final/result) cell by the updated v cell
      z[x][y] += v[x][y];
      //in short z[x][y] += v[x][y] + ((v[-1][0] + v[+1][0] + v[0][-1] + v[0][+1]) / 4 - v[x][y])
      //scale sin(z) and cos(z) results to 0-255
      rs = sin(z[x][y]) + 1.0;
      gc = cos(z[x][y]) + 1.0;
      rv = rs * 128;
      gv = gc * 128;
      //contrain to 0-255
      if(rv < 0)   rv = 0;
      if(rv > 255) rv = 255;
      if(gv < 0)   gv = 0;
      if(gv > 255) gv = 255;
      //cast to int and shift
      r = ((int)(rv) << 16);
      g = ((int)(gv) << 8);
      //average sin/cos results = use the sin/cos results used for red/green channels, scale them by half (128) brightness and add them up
      //then subtract that from the max (255) to invert the alpha(transparency) value
      int alpha = 255-(int)((rs * 128) + (gc * 128));
      int argb = alpha << 24 | r | g | b;
      canvas.pixels[width*y+x] = argb;
    }
  }
  canvas.updatePixels();
  image(canvas,0,0);
  fill(0);
  text((int)frameRate+"fps",15,15);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void move() {
  if (mouseX > -1    &&    mouseX < width    &&    mouseY > -1    &&    mouseY < height) {
    v[mouseX][mouseY] = randomGaussian() * TAU;

  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseClicked() { move(); }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void mouseDragged() { move(); }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int screenshotCount=1;
void keyPressed() {
  if (key ==' ') {
    canvas.save("result"+nf(screenshotCount,4)+".png");
    println("screenshot saved");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have the time to get into more detail and provide a fast working solution, but I can provide some pointers that may help:

This looks like a simplified [BZ or Grey Scott reaction diffusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JAqrRnKFHo) simulation:

[image: youtube video preview]

Check out [Daniel Shiffman's video tutorial on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV9ny785UNc): it will help you understand the algorithm better and write a more efficient implementation.

[image: Daniel Shiffman Reaction Diffusion]

There are a couple more hardcore methods of speeding this up that come to mind:

1. Parallelize the task on the GPU, rewriting the algorithm as a [Processing GLSL shader (PShader)](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/) - additionally, if you don't mind slightly different implementation, it might be easier to tweak [Shadertoy reaction diffusion fragment shaders](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=reaction%20diffusion) to run as PShaders (e.g. [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsG3z1) or [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKXzw))
2. Parallelize the task on the CPU (see [Java Multiprocessing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) [resources](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes6/c12/s3.html) - sorta dry material)

[image: shader toy reaction diffusion 1]

[image: shader toy reaction diffusion 2]

Comment: Hi. George. Also a huge thanks to you for all the input! I'm gonna go through everything thoroughly today and post here again once I come across any useful results to my current problem.

Comment: Dang George. I always love your answers. I almost didn't try answering this one because I knew you'd come around with something that blew mine out of the water!

Comment: Hi George, I am continuing to work may way through the code as well as all the resources you have provided with high hopes of eventually figuring this out. I have a small follow up question you might be able to help me with, since I haven't got a full grasp on the code yet. Do you think there is a way to change the background color (currently grey) to be white or even transparent? Or maybe you can just point me to where in the code the background color is determined. I haven't quite got it yet. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Notice these lines: ```r = ((int)((sin(z[x][y]) + 1) * 128) << 16);
      g = ((int)((cos(z[x][y]) * 128)) << 8);
      pixels[width*y+x] = 0xff000000 | r | g | b;```. The ```b``` part is obvious, simply change the value before the loops, in this section:```int r,g,b = 255;```
```r``` and ```g``` are computed, but ```sin()``` and ```cos``` are used, so that's pretty flexible to play with since both functions return a value between -1.0 and 1.0, therefore play with what is currently ```128```. increasing/decreasing these values will control the amount of red/green

Comment: @JohnGalt I've actually added an example up there in the answer that maps the colours so the background is white.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Again, so much thanks over here for all your help. I've implemented your solution for changing the background to white into the code which worked just fine. But do you know why the code now delivers a graphics with a hard edge instead of the gradients it had before (I've added a couple of screenshot to my original question comparing the two results)?

Comment: @JohnGalt I think it was a matter of clamping the values: ensuring they are within 0-255 range. I've updated the function above to illustrate this and added some comments that should help explain how the cell values map to colours. Try to tinker with the values, mess it up up, have fun, learn by experimenting :)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Amazing, thanks you so much, this really helps me make my way through the code and get where I want to. I'm a graphic designer and I'm actually using this in my professional work; and your help is so invaluable, especially since I'm learning a great deal on my own through it. Thanks again:)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Now, do you think its possible to create a transparent background (is there even a transparency option in Processing)? So far I've hit upon `tint()` but I understand that this only applies to loaded images. I suppose a more accurate question regarding my current problem would be: Is there a way to save to output of the code in separate layers? By that I mean somehow using `PGraphics`in order to separate the generated blobs from the background. Let me know if you think its more appropriate to discuss this problem in a new question instead of here:)

Comment: Please post a separate question for this specific topic. Meanwhile, as a designer workaround using Photoshop, how about using the **Quick Selection Tool** or **Select > Color Range** then play with selection feather radius to select...or even easier - just use multiple layers, keeping the image from processing on top, but setting the blend mode to **Multiply** (so dark pixels become opaque and bright (white) pixels become transparent)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Merci once again, George. I've worked with various Photoshop work-arounds to solve this before, with ok results. That's why I'm now looking into a code-based solution. But, as you said, I'll keep investigating into that direction via a separate question. Have a good day:)

Comment: I've posted yet another update with comments. Notice this is using a separate buffer to draw into: ```PGraphics``` as you suggested will work, but since it's only using pixel values ```PImage``` will be suffice. I've explained how the mapping from ```sin()/cos()``` to other values works, but not how bytes and colour channels do, so I'm guessing this is a tricky part coming from a graphic design background. I can expand on that in a separate answer if it helps.