# equations optimization - reaction diffusion - java

Tags: java, processing, equation

I'm working on [Gray Scott patterns](http://mrob.com/pub/comp/xmorphia/) with java (and [Processing](https://processing.org/))
I would like to optimize it. 
I haven't any GPU-acceleration skill. So I try to optimize the equations:

```
U[i][j] += ( U*lapU - uvv + F*(1 - u) ) * 1.38 ;
V[i][j] += ( V*lapV + uvv - (K+F)*v   ) * 0.63 ;
```

But maybe there is also to do arround, here is the function.

If you got any ideas to increase the speed ...

```
float uvv, u, v, diffU, diffV, F, K, lapU, lapV;
float[] MINI = { 0.00, 0.01, 0.03, 0.005 }; 
float[] MAXI = { 0.15, 0.08, 0.11, 0.05 }; 

PImage reactionDiffusion (PImage img) {

  int W = img.width, H = img.height;  
  int[][] offsetW = new int[W][2], offsetH = new int[H][2];
  float[][]  U = new float[W][H],  V = new float[W][H];
  float time = millis();

  //  INITIALISATION
  for (int i = 0; i < W; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < H; ++j) {
      U[i][j] = 0.15 ;
      V[i][j] = 0.7  ;
    }
  }  

  // init parameters
  float[][][] fkuv = new float[W][H][4];  

  for (int i = 0; i<W; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j<H; ++j){
        fkuv[i][j][0] = map( i, 0, H, MINI[0], MAXI[0] );
        fkuv[i][j][1] = map( j, 0, W, MAXI[1], MINI[0] );  
        fkuv[i][j][2] = map(150,0,200,0,MAXI[2]);
        fkuv[i][j][3] = map(50,0,200,0,MAXI[3]);
    }
  }
  //Set up offsets
  for (int i=0; i < W; ++i) { offsetW[i][0] = i-1; offsetW[i][1] = i+1; }
  for (int i=0; i < H; ++i) { offsetH[i][0] = i-1; offsetH[i][1] = i+1; }
  offsetW[0][0] = 0; offsetW[W-1][1] = W-1;
  offsetH[0][0] = 0; offsetH[H-1][1] = H-1;

  for (int n = 0; n< 2000 ; ++n){ // itérations
    for (int i = 0; i < W; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < H; ++j) {

        F = fkuv[i][j][0] ;
        K = fkuv[i][j][1] ;

        u = U[i][j];  
        v = V[i][j]; 

        uvv = u*v*v;
        lapU = U[offsetW[i][0]][j] +U[offsetW[i][1]][j] +U[i][offsetH[j][0]] +U[i][offsetH[j][1]] -4*u;
        lapV = V[offsetW[i][0]][j] +V[offsetW[i][1]][j] +V[i][offsetH[j][0]] +V[i][offsetH[j][1]] -4*v;

        U[i][j] += ( U*lapU - uvv + F*(1 - u) ) * 1.38 ;
        V[i][j] += ( V*lapV + uvv - (K+F)*v   ) * 0.63 ;
      } 
    }
  }
  img.loadPixels();
    int pShift;
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
        pShift = int( U[i][j]*255 ) ;
        img.pixels[j*W+i] = 0xff000000 | (pShift << 16) | (pShift << 8) | pShift  ;
      }
    }
  img.updatePixels();

  println("time : "+ ( millis()-time ) /1000) ; 

  return img;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can find a few optimisation tips in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350644/high-resolution-processing-output/40353261#40353261).

In terms of GPU acceleration, you don't need to learn everything. You should be able to get away with understanding the difference between vertex and fragment shaders and how to use uniform variables. Check out this [awesome PShader tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/).

There are also fragment PShader examples within Processing.
Once you get the hang of it, you could port a reaction diffusion from [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) to Processing (with very minimal tweaks).

[image: reaction diffusion fragment shader]

Here's an very rough example porting [this shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKXzw)

```
//ReactionDiffusion
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdKXzw

PShader bufA,shader;

void setup(){
  size(640,480,P2D);
  noStroke();

  //uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
  //uniform vec2 resolution;
  //uniform vec2 mouse;
  //uniform float time;
  bufA = loadShader("BufA.frag");
  bufA.set("resolution",(float)width,(float)height);
  //uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
  //uniform vec3 iChannelResolution[4];
  //uniform vec2 resolution;
  //uniform float time;
  shader = loadShader("shader.frag");
  shader.set("resolution",(float)width,(float)height);
  shader.set("iChannelResolution[0]",(float)width,(float)height,72);

}
void draw(){

  bufA.set("time",frameCount * .1);
  bufA.set("mouse",(float)mouseX,(float)mouseY,mousePressed ? 1 : 0,mousePressed && mouseButton == RIGHT ? 1 : 0);

  shader(bufA);
  background(0);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  bufA.set("iChannel0",get());
  //2nd pass
  shader.set("iChannel0",get());
  shader.set("time",frameCount * .1);
  shader(shader);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

**BufA.frag**

```
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec4 mouse;
uniform float time;

vec2 vv(vec2 uv, vec2 duv, vec2 texel) { 
    return texture2D(iChannel0, uv + (duv * texel)).xy; 
}

vec2 laplacian(vec2 ab, vec2 uv, vec2 texel) {
    return 
        ab * -1. +
        vv(uv, vec2(0., -1.), texel) * .2 +
        vv(uv, vec2(0., 1.), texel) * .2 +
        vv(uv, vec2(1., 0.), texel) * .2 +
        vv(uv, vec2(-1., 0.), texel) * .2 +
        vv(uv, vec2(-1., -1.), texel) * .05 +
        vv(uv, vec2(-1., 1.), texel) * .05 +
        vv(uv, vec2(1., -1.), texel) * .05 +
        vv(uv, vec2(1., 1.), texel) * .05;
}

void main()
{

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    vec2 texel = 1. / resolution.xy;
    vec4 m = mouse / resolution.xyxy;

    vec2 c = vec2(.5+cos(time)*0.3,.5+sin(time)*0.2);
    float lc = length(uv-c);

    if (m.z > 0. && length(m.xy-uv) < .02) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 1., 0., 1.);
    } else if (lc < .02-time*.003) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 1., 0., 1.);
    } else {

        vec2 ab = vv(uv, vec2(0., 0.), texel);
        vec2 lp = laplacian(ab, uv, texel);
        float a = ab.x;
        float b = ab.y;
        float la = lp.x;
        float lb = lp.y;
        float f = .028+(uv.y+c.y)*.0035;
        float k = .055+(uv.x+c.x)*.003;
        float dx = mod((time+uv.x+uv.y)*.5, .8);
        float da = .4+dx;
        float db = .2+dx*.5;


        float na = a + (da * la - a*b*b + f*(1.-a));
        float nb = b + (db * lb + a*b*b - (k+f)*b);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(na, nb, 0., 1.);
    }

}
```

**shader.frag**

```
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
uniform vec3 iChannelResolution[4];
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float time;

struct C_Sample
{
    vec3 vAlbedo;
    vec3 vNormal;
};

C_Sample SampleMaterial(const in vec2 vUV, sampler2D sampler,  const in vec2 vTextureSize, const in float fNormalScale)
{
    C_Sample result;

    vec2 vInvTextureSize = vec2(1.0) / vTextureSize;

    vec3 cSampleNegXNegY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2(-1.0, -1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSampleZerXNegY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 0.0, -1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSamplePosXNegY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 1.0, -1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);

    vec3 cSampleNegXZerY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2(-1.0, 0.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSampleZerXZerY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 0.0, 0.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSamplePosXZerY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 1.0, 0.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);

    vec3 cSampleNegXPosY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2(-1.0,  1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSampleZerXPosY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 0.0,  1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);
    vec3 cSamplePosXPosY = clamp(texture2D(sampler, vUV + (vec2( 1.0,  1.0)) * vInvTextureSize.xy).ggb*2., 0., 1.);

    // convert to linear    
    vec3 cLSampleNegXNegY = cSampleNegXNegY * cSampleNegXNegY;
    vec3 cLSampleZerXNegY = cSampleZerXNegY * cSampleZerXNegY;
    vec3 cLSamplePosXNegY = cSamplePosXNegY * cSamplePosXNegY;

    vec3 cLSampleNegXZerY = cSampleNegXZerY * cSampleNegXZerY;
    vec3 cLSampleZerXZerY = cSampleZerXZerY * cSampleZerXZerY;
    vec3 cLSamplePosXZerY = cSamplePosXZerY * cSamplePosXZerY;

    vec3 cLSampleNegXPosY = cSampleNegXPosY * cSampleNegXPosY;
    vec3 cLSampleZerXPosY = cSampleZerXPosY * cSampleZerXPosY;
    vec3 cLSamplePosXPosY = cSamplePosXPosY * cSamplePosXPosY;

    result.vAlbedo = cLSampleNegXNegY;  

    vec3 vScale = vec3(0.3333);

    float fSampleNegXNegY = dot(cLSampleNegXNegY, vScale);
    float fSampleZerXNegY = dot(cLSampleZerXNegY, vScale);
    float fSamplePosXNegY = dot(cLSamplePosXNegY, vScale);

    float fSampleNegXZerY = dot(cLSampleNegXZerY, vScale);
    float fSampleZerXZerY = dot(cLSampleZerXZerY, vScale);
    float fSamplePosXZerY = dot(cLSamplePosXZerY, vScale);

    float fSampleNegXPosY = dot(cLSampleNegXPosY, vScale);
    float fSampleZerXPosY = dot(cLSampleZerXPosY, vScale);
    float fSamplePosXPosY = dot(cLSamplePosXPosY, vScale);


    // Sobel operator - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

    vec2 vEdge;
    vEdge.x = (fSampleNegXNegY - fSamplePosXNegY) * 0.25 
            + (fSampleNegXZerY - fSamplePosXZerY) * 0.5
            + (fSampleNegXPosY - fSamplePosXPosY) * 0.25;

    vEdge.y = (fSampleNegXNegY - fSampleNegXPosY) * 0.25 
            + (fSampleZerXNegY - fSampleZerXPosY) * 0.5
            + (fSamplePosXNegY - fSamplePosXPosY) * 0.25;

    result.vNormal = normalize(vec3(vEdge * fNormalScale, 1.0));    

    return result;
}

void main()
{   
    vec2 vUV = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

    C_Sample materialSample;

    float fNormalScale = 10.0;
    materialSample = SampleMaterial( vUV, iChannel0, iChannelResolution[0].xy, fNormalScale );

    float fLightHeight = 0.5;
    float fViewHeight = 2.0;

    vec3 vSurfacePos = vec3(vUV, 0.0);

    vec3 vViewPos = vec3(0.5, 0.5, fViewHeight);

    vec3 vLightPos = vec3( vec2(sin(time*.5),cos(time*.5)) * 0.25 + 0.5 , fLightHeight);

    vec3 vDirToView = normalize( vViewPos - vSurfacePos );
    vec3 vDirToLight = normalize( vLightPos - vSurfacePos );

    float fNDotL = clamp( dot(materialSample.vNormal, vDirToLight), 0.0, 1.0);
    float fDiffuse = fNDotL;

    vec3 vHalf = normalize( vDirToView + vDirToLight );
    float fNDotH = clamp( dot(materialSample.vNormal, vHalf), 0.0, 1.0);
    float fSpec = pow(fNDotH, 10.0) * fNDotL * 0.5;

    vec3 vResult = materialSample.vAlbedo * fDiffuse + fSpec;

    vResult = sqrt(vResult);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vResult,1.0);
}
```

Additionally you should check out [toxiclibs](http://toxiclibs.org/). It already implements the same paper as the [GrayScott](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/simutils/toxi/sim/grayscott/GrayScott.html) class in the [simutils](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/simutils/) package.

Here's one of the examples:

```
/**
 * <p>GrayScottToneMap shows how to use the ColorGradient & ToneMap classes of the
 * colorutils package to create a tone map for rendering the results of
 * the Gray-Scott reaction-diffusion.</p>
 *
 * <p><strong>Usage:</strong><ul>
 * <li>click + drag mouse to draw dots used as simulation seed</li>
 * <li>press any key to reset</li>
 * </ul></p>
 */

/* 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Karsten Schmidt
 * 
 * This demo & library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/
 * 
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

import toxi.sim.grayscott.*;
import toxi.math.*;

import toxi.color.*;

int NUM_ITERATIONS = 10;

GrayScott gs;
ToneMap toneMap;

void setup() {
  size(256,256);
  gs=new GrayScott(width,height,false);
  gs.setCoefficients(0.021,0.076,0.12,0.06);
  // create a color gradient for 256 values
  ColorGradient grad=new ColorGradient();
  // NamedColors are preset colors, but any TColor can be added
  // see javadocs for list of names:
  // http://toxiclibs.org/docs/colorutils/toxi/color/NamedColor.html
  grad.addColorAt(0,NamedColor.BLACK);
  grad.addColorAt(128,NamedColor.RED);
  grad.addColorAt(192,NamedColor.YELLOW);
  grad.addColorAt(255,NamedColor.WHITE);
  // this gradient is used to map simulation values to colors
  // the first 2 parameters define the min/max values of the
  // input range (Gray-Scott produces values in the interval of 0.0 - 0.5)
  // setting the max = 0.33 increases the contrast
  toneMap=new ToneMap(0,0.33,grad);
}

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    gs.setRect(mouseX, mouseY,20,20);
  }
  loadPixels();
  // update the simulation a few time steps
  for(int i=0; i<NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    gs.update(1);
  }
  // read out the V result array
  // and use tone map to render colours
  for(int i=0; i<gs.v.length; i++) {
    pixels[i]=toneMap.getARGBToneFor(gs.v[i]);
  }
  updatePixels();
}

void keyPressed() {
  gs.reset();
}
```